# How can I use the ADD instruction with MASM?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

Here is my code fragment:

```
    .data
Num1    equ     40h
Num2    equ     41h
Var1    dword   0
Var2    dword   0
;----------------------------------------------------------------------
    align   4
    .code       ;insert executable instructions below
main    PROC        ;program execution begins here
    mov Var1, Num1
    mov Var2, Num2

    add Var1, Var2
```

I am trying to use the ADD instruction but I get the following error:

```
error A2070: invalid instruction operands
```

This error is related to the ADD line.
If I omit that line the program runs fine.

Comment: At least one of the operands need to be a register. You should be getting the same error with the `mov`s.

Comment: @Mysticial `mov r/m, imm` is encodable, right? `C7 /0`?

Comment: @harold I'm not too familiar with the assembly declaration syntax. That's why I didn't make it an answer. I've never seen `equ` before. But if it's treating it as an immediate, then that would explain it.

Comment: @Mysticial it should, that's essentially what `equ` is for

Comment: @Mysticial Then, How can I add/sub/mult two vars?

Comment: @harold Ah thanks. Guess I learned something today. :)

Comment: @MIH1406 You move `Var1` into a register. Then add `Var2` to it. Then move it back into memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add two memory location to each other, you should use one of the registers as a second operand

```
 .data
Num1    equ     40h
Num2    equ     41h
;----------------------------------------------------------------------
    align   4
    .code       ;insert executable instructions below
    main    PROC        ;program execution begins here

    mov ax, Num2

    add ax, Num1
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use `eax` since it's a `dword`?

Comment: yeah,but i removed the var1 and var2 from the program because they are not necessary and they just add memory read/write overhead.

Comment: Equates are Assemble time constants and have nothing to do with a running program.

Comment: yup but 
Var1    dword   0
Var2    dword   0
are memory variables